# Load a img using gd library

Tags: php, gd, assets, barcode

I'm trying to generate a barcode using this: https://github.com/davidscotttufts/php-barcode/.

This method requires to install gd library.

I install this library like this on my linux based server:

```
$ apt-get install php5-gd
```

After the instalation I restarded the server and looked if it was instaled like this:

```
php -m
```

And it was.

Now I added this line to my code to genarate a barcode(I'm generating the link with the twig function "asset"):

```html
<img alt="testing" src="{{ asset('bundles/kopictadmin/code/barcode.php?text=testing') }}"/>
```

This gives my the 'Alt' attribute instead of the picture. I'm generating css just like this only branching of to 'css' folder instead of the 'code' folder.

Somebody any idea whats wrong?

Comment: So, what is the generated asset link? It's probably not found or you're getting some other error if the image is returning you the `alt` parameter.

Comment: assetic creates the path in front of /Bundles/ So it doesn't matter what's infront. Because its always the same. I generate the links to css like this: asset('bundles/kopictadmin/css/style.css'. And this works fine

Comment: The generated link actually gives you a valid image? Can you open that image link in your browser?

Comment: Well. It gives me the 'image not found' image. And afther this the alt text. When I go to the link directly it downloads the barcode.php

Comment: Well, it should open the image correctly if you want the `img` tag to work. That's your problem. The code is not correctly loading that .php file into an image.

Comment: what do you suggest I do now?

Comment: Fix the code that generates the image.

Comment: could you answer the quistion so I can accept you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `img` tag returns the `alt` value because the image that you have provided is not a correct image.

You need to fix the code itself in `barcode.php` so that the image is properly created and should probably check the result in the browser first so you know that the result of calling `barcode.php` is actually an image.